# Reiniciar o Celular

Tags: java, android

Alguma dica de código para reiniciar o celular após uma ação?

Exemplo: Após realizar o backup, preciso que o celular reinicie para terminar as configurações.

Comment: Se não me engano, não é possivel um app fazer isso, exige privilégios elevados(root), o que diminuirá drasticamente os usuarios do seu app.

Comment: Veja essa pergunta no SOEn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984849/restart-android-device-programmatically

Comment: acha mais viavel colocar uma mensagem de alerta então? que a alteração só surtirá efeito após a reinicialização ?

Comment: O sistema ou sua aplicação precisa reiniciar? Caso seja o sistema, por que o sistema precisa reiniciar? Você só consegue fazer o sistema reiniciar se sua aplicação estiver instalada na pasta `/system/app` (que é inviável, a não ser que você tenha acesso root ao dispositivo do usuário antes dele usar o app) e com a permissão de reboot. Acho uma notificação algo muito volátil para uma coisa que parece ser importante, pois o usuário pode ignorar e o reboot pode demorar muito a acontecer

Comment: Chiavone, é que criei um Boadcast Receiver para reagendar todos os alarmes quando reiniciado o celular, lendo uma tabela do banco de dados para nao perde-los. Restaurando o backup, iria reiniciar o celular para reagendar todos e fazer a aplicação rodar corretamente. porem, coloquei um AlertDialog notificando depois da restauração, que o sistema deverá ser reiniciado

Comment: Porque não usar outra mensagem para fazer o reagendamento, além da mensagem de reboot? Após a restauração, você poderia emitir uma mensagem que você mesmo captura. Isso permitiria que a instância do receiver seja a mesma, é só registrá-lo para ouvir outros Broadcast Message.

Answer (score 0):

Coloca essa  permissão no seu manifesto

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"/>
```

Roda esse código

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
pm.reboot(null);
```

Comment: A permissão [android.permission.REBOOT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REBOOT) não pode ser "adquirida" por uma aplicação normal.